# Check equicontinuity of functions family

Tags: functional-analysis

I have this family of functions:
$$M = \{x(t) = (t-1)^{2n}, n\in\mathbb Z\}, t \in [0,1]$$

What should I do to check equicontinuity?

Comment: You could start by sketching the first few of these and see what the graphs are doing. They are going to start getting very steep near $t=0$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. And how will it help me?

Comment: It will help you to decide whether the family is equicontinuous or not so you will know what you want to prove.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I can't understand how that fact helps me with decision. Could you explain me?

Comment: Think about the meaning of equicontinuity. What does the fact that these functions are converging to something discontinuous tell you?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Well, I can't connect "graph's are getting very steep near $t=0$" and conclusion about equicontinuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $x_n(t):=(1-t)^{2n}$; then $|x_n(1)-x_n(1-1/n)|=(1-1/n)^{2n}$ which converges to $e^2\neq 0$. If equi-continuity at $1$ held, then so would the following convergence $\lim_{n\to +\infty}|x_n(1)-x_n(1-1/n)|=0$ because the same $\delta$ in the definition of continuity would work.